# WordPress with Elementor Latest Version Export Kit doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have latest WordPress v6.2 and latest Elementor v3.12.0 and Hello theme v2.7.1. I made some page, section and container templates that I’d like to export. When I go to Elementor > Tools > Import / Export Kit and click on Start Export, I am just getting message “App could not be loaded”.

This is the error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
at app.min.js?ver=3.12.0:3:40724
at Dr (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73052)
at Or (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73238)
at xl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:92482)
at react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:89829
at v (react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:3385)
at ce (react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:5527)
at A. (load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,hoverIntent,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.2:13:16077)
at P (load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,hoverIntent,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.2:13:15885)
at MessagePort.E (load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,hoverIntent,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.2:13:15942)
```

My server has ZIP support and has memory limit set to 512MB. PHP versions I tried are 7.4, 8.0, 8.1 and 8.2.

I need help immediately

Thank You